# How do I sinon.stub a nested method with a callback?

Tags: node.js, callback, stub, sinon

I need to test a method that includes a sub-method which makes a call to an API server. I’d like to stud this internal sub-method, but I can’t seem to do that. Here’s an example:

```
var requests = require('./requests.js');

var utilityClass = {
  methodCreatesObject: function (callback) {

    // Here’s the method I’m trying to stub:
    requests.makeCallToAPI(requestObject, function (err, responseFromAPI) {

      doSomethingWithResponse(responseFromAPI, function (err, finalObject) {

        if (err) {
          callback(err, null);
        } else {
          callback(null, finalObject); // <- Want to test the value of finalObject
        }

      });

    });

  }
}
```

So, my test looks something like this (updated to show loading `requests.js` before `utility.js`):

```
var should   = require('should'),
    Joi      = require('joi'),
    sinon    = require('sinon'),
    requests = require('../lib/modules/requests.js'),
    utility  = require('../lib/modules/utility.js')
    ;

// Start my tests:
describe('Method', function () {

  before(function () {
    var fakeAPIresponse = { ... }
    sinon.stub(requests, 'makeCallToAPI').yield(null, fakeAPIresponse);
  });

  it('should produce a well-formed finalObject', function (done) {
    utilityClass.methodCreatesObject(function (err, response) {
      if (err) {
        done(err);
      } else {
        response.should.do.this.or.that;
        done();
      }
    });
  });

});
```

As I understand it, `.yields()` should try to run the first callback it detects in the arguments and feed its own arguments to it (resulting in `doSomethingWithResponse(responseFromAPI, function () {...})`). However, when running mocha, I’m getting an error indicating that the API server could not be reached, which suggests that the real `requests.makeCallToAPI()` is being called, and not my stub.

I must be missing something. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you requiring the `request.js`? You will need to require request.js before you load up the module you want to test.

Edit 1: Using `sinon.js`

Here is a gist of what I meant: https://gist.github.com/limianwang/1114249de99c6a189384

Edit 2: Using `proxyquire`

If you are intending to test simply the `utilities` without concern of what actually happens within the `requests.makeAPICall`, you can use something like `proxyquire` to do the trick. If you are concerned with the actual logic within `requests.js`, you can use sinon.stub to stub out the actual `request.get` api.

Comment: You mean in the test file? I’m requiring `utilities.js` before `requests.js` at the beginning of the file (that is, outside of the `describe` statement). Should I require inside the describe statement?

Comment: @Alfonso Swap the order of the requires. In your test, load up `require('../lib/modules/requests.js')` before `require('../lib/modules/utility.js')`. This will guarantee that you have the object stubbed before you make the API call.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out after dinner. Should I stub before requiring `utility.js` as well?

Comment: Still ignoring the stub.

Comment: I updated the question to reflect that even when loading `requests.js` before `utility.js`, the stub is ignored.

Comment: Give me a few mins @Alfonso I'll mock up something and do some testing with what you provided me.

Comment: @Alfonso https://gist.github.com/limianwang/1114249de99c6a189384 make sure you install mocha/chai/sinon. It worked for me. Updated the original answer with gist.

Comment: Does it make a difference that `requests.js` needs to be called with an argument? Like so: `var requests = require('./requests.js')(apiCredentials)`. `requests.js` returns an object with API credentials preloaded into the object’s methods. (Sorry I hadn’t mentioned this. Didn’t seem like it should make a difference until I saw your example.)

Comment: I also noticed that your example works even if `requests.js` is loaded after `utility`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66002/discussion-between-alfonso-and-lwang135).